# How do I take input value and append it to new element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, createelement

This is what I want to do: On click of button, create a "p" element, give it an id, append it to parent div, then take the value of the input field and append that to the "innerHTML" of the newly created "p" element. Please help!

html:

```
<div id="main_container">
    <h1 class="hero">TITLE</h1>
    <div id="content_container">
        <form id="form">
            <label id="create_name">Create a username:</label>
            <input id="input1"></input>
            <button id="usr_btn">button</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#usr_btn').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('#input1').val() != null) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var userName = document.createElement('p');
        userName.id = 'name_created';
        $('#name_created').append($('#content_container'));
        $('#name_created').append($('#input1').val());
    }
});
```

Comment: I can see some great answers but one thing you will want to add is something to create unique `id`'s to ensure the id isn't being duplicated OR have something in place to stop the user from submitting the same username more than once. This can cause problems later depending on what you need the `id`'s for.

Comment: I'll have to look into how to do that, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: One way of doing this is to have a variable with the value of 0, each time the function is fires +1 to your variable and place that in the ID, Example `var step=0;` Inside of your function place `step++;` for the id attribute have `"some_name"+step`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
//Declare the step variable
var step=0; 
$('#usr_btn').on('click', function (e) {
        if ($('#input1').val() != null) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //Increment ID's to make them unique   
             step++;
            // using jQuery to create a <p> element, with
            // an id of 'name_created', and using
            // the 'text' property to set the textContent
            // of the element:
            var userName = $('<p>', {
                'id' : 'name_created'+step,
                'text' : $('#input1').val()
            // appending the created element t '#content_container':
            }).appendTo('#content_container');
        }
    });
```

One problem in your own posted code is that the line:

```
$('#name_created').append($('#content_container'));
```

appends the element identified by its `id` of 'content_container' to the created element, whereas your question suggests you want to add the created-element to the `#content_container` element.

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [Creating an element with jQuery: `jQuery(html, attributes)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes).

Comment: Okay, this solves it and thanks for the tip on append() vs appendTo() I was getting those confused.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help; it's probably easier to keep them straight for those of us speaking English as their primary (or only) language; but if a jQuery method seems not to be doing what it should, it's always worth revisiting the documentation (it genuinely seems to have the best API documentation of any library or language I've worked with, limited though that is).

Comment: @DavidThomas I hope you don't mind but I really like this answer but wanted to add the unique IDs as IDs shouldn't be used more than once. This does answer the question with/without the id duplication but i didn't see much point in posts a new answer then you have it here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (including validation to ensure you don't duplicate id's - which is invalid in html):

```js
$('#usr_btn').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($('#input1').val() != null) {
    var user = $('#input1').val();
    var count = $('#' + user).length;
    if (count == 0) {
      $('#content_container').append("<p id=" + user + ">" + user + "</p>");
    } else {
      alert("User is already there!");
    }


  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_container">
  <h1 class="hero">TITLE</h1>
  <div id="content_container">
    <form id="form">
      <label id="create_name">Create a username:</label>
      <input id="input1"></input>
      <button id="usr_btn">button</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the jQuery selector will not find the newly created `#name_created` element as it is not part of the DOM. Try this:

```js
$('#usr_btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#input1').val() != '') {
        $('<p />', { id: 'name_created', text: $('#input1').val() }).appendTo('#content_container');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_container">
    <h1 class="hero">TITLE</h1>
    <div id="content_container">
        <form id="form">
            <label id="create_name">Create a username:</label>
            <input id="input1" />
            <button id="usr_btn">button</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code creates the new `p` tag, applies the values for `text` and `id` to it, then appends it to the `#content_container`. Note that your code may end up with duplicate `id` attributes if the button is pressed repeatedly. You may be better off changing the `id` to a `class`.

Comment: I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

Comment: @MarkusHallcyon my bad, typo. Updated answer